# Rank of a real matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, linear-transformations, matrix-calculus, matrix-rank

Let $T$ be a noninvertible matrix in $M_n(\mathbb R)$ and $L$ be a one-rank matrix on $T\mathcal R^n$. Now, consider $TRT=LT$ on $\mathcal R^n$ where $R$ is a matrix in $M_n(\mathbb R)$.

Is the rank of $R$ one? Can we get $R=T_{1}^{-1}LT$ where $T_{1}^{-1}$ is inverse of the restriction of $T$ on $T\mathcal R^n$?

Comment: Certainly, if $T = 0$ then $R$ can be any matrix.

Comment: Yes. But $T$ is not zero.

Comment: Okay, but you never said so in the question

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no.  For example, take
$$
T = \pmatrix{1\\ &1 \\&&0},  \quad L = \pmatrix{1\\&0\\&&0}, \quad 
R = \pmatrix{1\\ &0\\ &&1}
$$
and note that $TR = L$.  Notably, if $T$ has rank $1$, then $R$ might have any rank.

Comment: Thanks. Now, if I don't make the mistake, $RT=T_{1}LT$. So, the rank of $RT$ is one.

Comment: Sure. So is that significant?

Comment: No. Well, what conditions must be for $T$ and $S$ that $R$ can be one-rank?

Comment: @444 see, this is why you provide *context* when you ask questions.  Why do we care if $R$ has rank one?

Comment: That's right. I must put it in the question. I wanted get an element such as $R$ that be one-rank by this way.

Comment: I think made a mistake. I'm sorry.